# Use class function as __init__ parameter default value

Tags: python

I made a class and in its `__init__` function I'd like to use its class function as a default value. Is this possible?

It should look something like this:

```
class Stepsize():

    def __init__(self, stepsize=Stepsize.check_stepsize()): 
        self.stepsize = stepsize

    async def check_stepsize(self): 
        return
```

However, the interpreter gives me back

```
NameError: name 'Stepsize' is not defined
```

Comment: No, it is not possible. Default values are evaluated at the time that the function is created, and at that time, the class does not exist yet - the function must be created before the class can be created. It is possible to hack the default values associated with the function later, but this comes with numerous drawbacks. The standard solution is to use `None` as a placeholder for the default value, explicitly check for that, and do the logic inside the function. That way, `Stepsize.check_stepsize()` only happens when the method is actually called.

Comment: Understood, that was very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Does the function have to be a class method? That is, does `check_stepsize` actually make use of the class object `self`?

Comment: In reality this class inherits from two other classes because they provide information needed for the functionality. I'm trying to follow SOLID principles and keep functionality in classes separated from eachother.

Comment: There *are* ways that you can modify a function's default arguments after creation, but there are drawbacks to that in terms of code quality; moreover, it still doesn't solve the problem that the default value is determined ahead of time, before the function is called.